# does anyone know how docker log flush interval is set

Tags: docker, logging, go

Does anyone know how to set docker log flush interval?

In other words, when you use command `docker logs -f`, where the log flush interval is set? I'm using docker SDK:

```
readerCloser, err := cli.ContainerLogs(context.Background(), container.ID[:10], clo)
```

to retrieve log, but now it seems time interval is set to 1 minute, how to change the interval?